# how to code the utility functions in React without cluttering the component it'self

Tags: reactjs

I have build this small react app with 3 components showing weatherforcaset from an api. 
I am not sure how I have handled the utils functions in a separate node module is the correct way as it's pretty adhoc, mainly to do with the date handling and creating another 5 arrays with the data received from the api.

https://github.com/c-science1/weatherForecastReact/

Please can someone advise me if there is a better way if doing the same?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can minimize the code in the function while keeping the DRY principle. You should refactor the following method:

```
this.createNewLists = function (dayName, itemP){
        let itemDate = new Date(itemP.dt_txt);
        let currentDate = new Date();
        let nextDate = new Date(); ;

        if (itemDate.getDate() == currentDate.getDate() ){
            this.day1.push(itemP);
            this.day1Name = dayName;
        }

        nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (itemDate.getDate() === nextDate.getDate()){
            this.day2.push(itemP);
            this.day2Name = dayName;
        }

       nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate() + 1);
         if (itemDate.getDate() === nextDate.getDate()){
            this.day3.push(itemP);
            this.day3Name = dayName;
        }

        nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (itemDate.getDate() === nextDate.getDate()){
            this.day4.push(itemP);
            this.day4Name = dayName;
        }

        nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (itemDate.getDate() === nextDate.getDate()){
            this.day5.push(itemP);
            this.day5Name = dayName;
        }
    }
```

The pattern in this function are repeating them and you can better organize this code.

You can iterate from 1 to 5 (for the weekdays) and minimize your code and keep clean code and the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I would say for the size of your app it is just fine. Regarding things I might do differently, I would not use `utils` function wrapper, since you already have module serving as namespace.

As for `weatherImage` function I would probably put it into component file that uses it. If more than one component uses it, I would probably put it into `components/common.js`. `createNewLists` would probably also go to this module.

Comment: Thank you very much for the two good points! Makes much sense.

Comment: Well as old Sumerians used to say, nothing says thank you as up vote on the answer ;)